# App intro error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android

When creating an android app intro there is a memory lag error and application stopped.

```
public class SampleSlide extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID = "layoutResId";

    public static SampleSlide newInstance(int layoutResId) {
        SampleSlide sampleSlide = new SampleSlide();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID, layoutResId);
        sampleSlide.setArguments(args);
        return sampleSlide;
    }

    private int layoutResId;

    public SampleSlide() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID))
            layoutResId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: check this ref :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to use the code. simply define below thing in your activity which is define in the `manifest.xml` file to solve your problem.

```
<application
    ....
       android:largeHeap="true">
```